# Accessing an instance method of a ViewController From Another view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, properties, uiviewcontroller, instance

Let's say I have a view controller called vc1, which a synthesized property called property1, and i wants to access it from another view controller (vc2) and change it from vc2.

Now the methods created by the @syntisize to change and get properties are instance methods, so how can I get to them fro another view controller (do view controllers have instances in the app, and if so, what are they?)

Just to be clear I am using storyboards, so I never really instantiate the view controllers...

Comment: Do you have a reference from the vc2 to vc1?

Comment: Is vc2 loaded using a segue from vc1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VC1.m:

```
-(void) yourMethod {
     ...
}
```

VC2.m

```
YOURViewController * vc2 = [[YOURViewController alloc]init];
[vc yourMethod];
[vc release];
```

Make sure to import your `YOURViewController` in your other view .m file
Something like that should work.

Or if you're having problems, try this tutorial here:

[Tutorial on How-To Pass Data Between Two View Controllers](http://klanguedoc.hubpages.com/hub/IOS-5-Tutorial-on-How-To-Pass-Data-Between-Two-View-Controllers)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: -1 for the suggestion: "Or you can put it in app delegate so you can access it in different viewControllers.".

Comment: Oh sorry, going to edit it. I was thinking of an object/array. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

While you can do it the way you describe, I think the common technique (assuming VC1 has a segue to VC2) is a bit different, where VC2 will have a property that will be set by `prepareForSegue`. See [Configuring the Destination Controller When a Segue is Triggered](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH8-SW4) in the View Controller Programming Guide.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to link the storyboard views with the viewcontrollers so the view for vc1 would use the class vc1 etc for the rest (I assume you have done this because this is important when coding for different views)

Then all you need to do is where ever you are calling the properties so lets say the `viewDidLoad` method, declare the view controller like this:

`- (void) viewDidLoad { 

vc1 *viewController;

// Now you change the variable I'll presume its a UILabel so I'll change its text
 [viewController.property1 setText:@"I changed a different views UILabel"];

}`

Let me know whether this works... Its worked for me before so should work